# Fragment Logo Animation High CPU Usage

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, animation, cpu

I have a logo that rotates in the Fragment infinitely ( Its a loading animation ).
the problem is that the CPU usage is very high during the said animation ( Hovering from 25 to 32 % ) while without animation it is only 3-5 %.
Moreover I have a similar animation in dialog but that also reports lower CPU usage of around 16-20 %.
(Tried setting Hardware layers but that doesnt make a difference).

How should I optimise the animation ?

```
  ImageView waitAnimation = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wait_animation);
        // Step1 : create the  RotateAnimation object
        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        // Step 2:  Set the Animation properties
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(2100);
        waitAnimation.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use ObjectAnimator? [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) is prefered way to animate views now.

Comment: Will that have an effect on the CPU usage ?

Comment: Just try it, Google have written, that it is more optimized.

Comment: I tried that but to no avail. The Usage is still high